# SpringRoo Controller Mapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-roo

Is there a way using the latest verions of Spring Roo to having this RequestMapping URL/value in this manner(s):

- `localhost/application/[generated-code]/menu`
- `localhost/application/[generated-code]/settings`
- `localhost/application/admin`

*`generated-code` is supplied to a column in the accounts table.*

*`menu`, `settings` and `admin` are Controllers having the class names `MenuController`, `SettingController` and `AdminController` respectively.*

*OPTIONAL: Since both `menu` and `settings` to share the same URL mapping, is there a way to have such validation on an abstract controller to implement the abstraction OOP concept.*

The idea was to put additional security feature to end-user by supplying them them their login URL and login account. The plan was in the application named: `application` both the admin users and end users share the same application build.

Is this feature possible using Spring-Roo, Spring MVC, and Spring Security? How can such be implemented?

**UPDATED**

@CodeChip comment to use `@PathVariable` can be a solution. But as stated in the question and on comment to @CodeChip suggestion, creating an abstract controller is a optimal approach.

Comment: You can use `@PathVariables` in your request mapping.

Comment: using `@PathVariables` may solve this problem but issue isn't solved yet. `@PathVariables` can only be annotated on method parameters. Is there a way to declare it as a global variable?

Comment: I have never tried it, but you can put an `@RequestMapping` at the class level of the controller.  Since adding it to a method accepts path variables in the URL, I don't see why adding it at the class level wouldn't.

Comment: @CodeChimp true adding `@PathVariables` values on the controller's `@RequestMapping` is a solution. Viewing from the code the OOP Concept of Abstraction is advisable to follow since `MenuController` and `SettingController` share the same validation for `[generated-code]`. I was wondering, from my previous comment, if `@PathVariables` can be placed in an abstract approach so that the methods/pages can follow the said approach.

Comment: In looking at the JavaDoc for the RequestMapping annotation, it does not appear that it is inheritable (inheritable annotations with have @Inherited in their definition).  Therefore, I do not believe would be possible to define an abstract Controller with a base RequestMapping that gets inherited down.  However, I do believe you can have the same path defined in two different Controllers at the class level, as long as there is something to differentiate at the handler method-level. You would have to experiment with that, though, as I have never tried it in practice.